# Running a specific funciton from command line

Tags: python, python-2.7

First, I apologize, I am very new to python and programming in general. I have a python script called test.py that has three different functions within it.

```
def greetings():
    print "Hello User"

def salutations():
    print "Nice to meet you!"

def goodbye():
    print "Have a pleasant day"
```

Now what I really want to do is run the script with an argument and call the correct function based on that function like this:

```
python test.py greetings
```

In this example I would want it to run the greetings function. I've tried messing around with sys.argv but everything I've tried falls short. If anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access command arguments via `sys.argv`, then get corresponding function from [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), and call it using `()`.

```
import sys

def greetings():
    print("Hello User")

def salutations():
    print ("Nice to meet you!")

def goodbye():
    print("Have a pleasant day")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func = sys.argv[1]
    locals()[func]()
```

Comment: Given that OP is "very new to Python and programming", perhaps you could give some explanation behind your answer.

Comment: @win_the_day_go_ducks You're welcome! Please accept my answer.

Comment: @brittenb Yeah, I append some explanation.

Comment: I found understanding [this useful](https://i.imgur.com/0tKjYlE.png) when starting to learn Python as well and passing in arguments to the script just as you asked... @win_the_day_go_ducks . . . Rather than a beer, you might [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that helped resolve your problem in case you didn't know how that works, that'd be a great sign of appreciation.